Negative Eigenvalues of the Woods-Saxon Nuclear Potential for Oxygen ND Eigensystem
I am trying to use ND Eigensystem to find the  eigenvalues of the Woods-Saxon Potential Schroedinger Equation for Oxygen. I've defined the potential and operator, but I know the functions given are incorrect because when I compare them to the harmonic oscillator solutions they are incorrect.
h = 1/2; V[r_] := (-V0)/(1 + E^((r - R)/a))
\[ScriptCapitalL] = -h^2*u''[r] + V[r]*u[r];

{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[\[ScriptCapitalL], u[r], {r, 0, 10}, 10];
Show[Plot[Evaluate[h*funs + vals], {r, 0, 10}], 
Plot[V[r], {r, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-50, 5}}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]


This is just the online example with changed potential function. Does the original example evaluate properly? What values did you put for V0, a, R?

...the + vals is just to create a waterfall type of plot.

@mikuszefski yes, the original example does evaluate properly. I used the standard values for the Woods Saxon Potential and oxygen: V0 = 50MeV, a = 0.67fm, and R =r0*A^(1/3) where r0 = 1.27fm and A = number of nucleons which for oxygen is 16

ok, but you have x in units of  1fm and y in units of 1MeV, right? Did you remove the PlotRange?

Try asking on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ or https://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=mathematica
